# How to add a CNN layer on top of BERT?

Tags: nlp, cnn, pytorch, transfer-learning, bert

I am just playing with **bert (Bidirectional Encoder Representation from Transformer)** 
[Research Paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805)

Suppose I want to add any other model or layers like Convolutional Neural Network layers (CNN), Non Linear (NL) layers on top of BERT model. **How can I do this?**

**I am not able to figure out where should I change in code of BERT.** I am using the pytorch implementation of [bert](https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-pretrained-BERT)
from huggingface.

*This is what I want to do:*
[image]
[image]

**Please show steps to implement this using sudo code** which will help me in implemention of cnn on top of BERT.

Answer (score 2):

## BERT:

```
import transformers
import torch

tokenizer = transformers.BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
bert_model = transformers.BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

max_seq = 100

def tokenize_text(df, max_seq):
    return [
        tokenizer.encode(text)[:max_seq] for text in df['text']
    ]

def pad_text(tokenized_text, max_seq):
    return np.array([el + [0] * (max_seq - len(el)) for el in tokenized_text])

def tokenize_and_pad_text(df, max_seq):
    tokenized_text = tokenize_text(df, max_seq)
    padded_text = pad_text(tokenized_text, max_seq)
    return torch.tensor(padded_text)

def targets_to_tensor(df):
    return torch.tensor(df['label'].values, dtype=torch.float32)

train_indices = tokenize_and_pad_text(small_train, max_seq)
val_indices = tokenize_and_pad_text(small_valid, max_seq)
test_indices = tokenize_and_pad_text(small_test, max_seq)

with torch.no_grad():
    x_train = bert_model(train_indices)[0]  
    x_val = bert_model(val_indices)[0]
    x_test = bert_model(test_indices)[0]

y_train = targets_to_tensor(small_train)
y_val = targets_to_tensor(small_valid)
y_test = targets_to_tensor(small_test)
```

## CNN:

```
import time
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from torch.autograd import Variable


class KimCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_num, embed_dim, class_num, kernel_num, kernel_sizes, dropout, static):
        super(KimCNN, self).__init__()
        V = embed_num
        D = embed_dim
        C = class_num
        Co = kernel_num
        Ks = kernel_sizes

        self.static = static
        self.embed = nn.Embedding(V, D)
        self.convs1 = nn.ModuleList([nn.Conv2d(1, Co, (K, D)) for K in Ks])
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(len(Ks) * Co, C)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        if self.static:
            x = Variable(x)
        x = x.unsqueeze(1)  # (N, Ci, W, D)
        x = [F.relu(conv(x)).squeeze(3) for conv in self.convs1]  # [(N, Co, W), ...]*len(Ks)
        x = [F.max_pool1d(i, i.size(2)).squeeze(2) for i in x]  # [(N, Co), ...]*len(Ks)
        x = torch.cat(x, 1)
        x = self.dropout(x)  # (N, len(Ks)*Co)
        logit = self.fc1(x)  # (N, C)
        output = self.sigmoid(logit)
        return output


n_epochs = 50
batch_size = 10
lr = 0.01
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
loss_fn = nn.BCELoss()

def generate_batch_data(x, y, batch_size):
    i, batch = 0, 0
    for batch, i in enumerate(range(0, len(x) - batch_size, batch_size), 1):
        x_batch = x[i : i + batch_size]
        y_batch = y[i : i + batch_size]
        yield x_batch, y_batch, batch
    if i + batch_size < len(x):
        yield x[i + batch_size :], y[i + batch_size :], batch + 1
    if batch == 0:
        yield x, y, 1
train_losses, val_losses = [], []

for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    start_time = time.time()
    train_loss = 0

    model.train(True)
    for x_batch, y_batch, batch in generate_batch_data(x_train, y_train, batch_size):
        y_pred = model(x_batch)
        y_batch = y_batch.unsqueeze(1)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_batch)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss += loss.item()

    train_loss /= batch
    train_losses.append(train_loss)
    elapsed = time.time() - start_time

    model.eval() # disable dropout for deterministic output
    with torch.no_grad(): # deactivate autograd engine to reduce memory usage and speed up computations
        val_loss, batch = 0, 1
        for x_batch, y_batch, batch in generate_batch_data(x_val, y_val, batch_size):
            y_pred = model(x_batch)
            y_batch = y_batch.unsqueeze(1)
            loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_batch)
            val_loss += loss.item()
        val_loss /= batch
        val_losses.append(val_loss)

    print(
        "Epoch %d Train loss: %.2f. Validation loss: %.2f. Elapsed time: %.2fs."
        % (epoch + 1, train_losses[-1], val_losses[-1], elapsed)
    )
```

This [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/identifying-hate-speech-with-bert-and-cnn-b7aa2cddd60d) explains well how to use CNN with BERT in Pytorch.

Answer (score 1):

You could use HuggingFace's BertModel ([transformers](https://huggingface.co/transformers/installation.html)) as the base layer for your model and just like how you would build a neural network in Pytorch, you can build on top of it. HuggingFace's other BertModels are built in the same way. For reference you can take a look at their TokenClassification code over [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/modeling_bert.html#BertForTokenClassification). This hasn't been mentioned in the documentation much and I think it should.

For Tensorflow however, you would have convert the Bert Model into a Keras layer. I haven't really gone through it much or tried it, but I think [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/fine-tuning-bert-with-keras-and-tf-module-ed24ea91cff2) blog post does a pretty good job of explaining it.